# Should I use 'I said to him' or 'I told him' in this dialogue?

Tags: word-choice

I wonder if I should use 'said' or 'told' in the following dialogue:

> I waited for too long.    He took her
>   away.
>
> I said to him crying,    "I saw her
>   first!"
>
> He said to me smiling,
>
> "finders keepers."

(by the way, is it correct to use "finders keepings" in this situation?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Tell** focuses on giving information.

> Please tell me your name.

**Say** focuses on the act of speaking

> Please say that again because I
>   didn't hear what you said.

I guess here, better to use "tell"

more info:

SAY:

- Say is used to report someone's
  words:

> ```
>   She said "I'm thirsty."
>
>
>  She said that she was thirsty.
> ```

- Say is followed by 'to' before the
  object:

> ```
>  Did she say that to you?
> ```

- Say is used to ask about languages :

> ```
>  How do you say 'water' in Spanish?
> ```

We say : 
   hello, goodbye, please, thank you, 
   congratulations, Merry Christmas, 
   Happy New Year, Happy Birthday!

TELL:

- Tell is used to inform or instruct :

> ```
>  Could you tell me the way to the station please?
>
>  Tell the children to go to bed!
> ```

- Tell is followed directly by the
  object :

> ```
>  Did she tell you her name?
> ```

- Tell is used for narration :

> ```
>  Tom is good at telling stories.
> ```

We tell : 
   the time, our name, the truth, lies, 
   the difference between two things.

Comment: So I should use "He told me" or "He said to me" in the "Finders, Keepers" part?

Comment: @Janochen: I think "He told me" is better in this case.

Answer (score 2):

I presume you're talking about the sentence:

> I said to him crying, "I saw her first!"

This isn't really clear, since *crying* can mean weeping or shouting. At least it would require a comma:

> I said to him, crying, "I saw her first!"

But if you mean *crying* as in *shouting out*, then why not simply say that?

> I cried, "I saw her first!"

Comment: @Robusto I mean crying (with tears). So is it OK to use `said to him` instead of `told him`?

Comment: @Robusto: Actually he was asking between "say" and "tell"... :D

Comment: @Robusto So should I change 'He said to me smiling,
' to 'He said to me, smiling,' too?

Comment: @janoChen: I would use a comma there, yes.

Comment: @Alenanno: I accidentally upticked your comment. Oh well ... in any case, I know what @janoChen was asking. I responded to what I thought the OP should have been asking. :)

Comment: @Robusto: Ahah no worries, I don't mind being upvoted :P So "I said to him" is equally accepted? I know it's grammatically correct but isn't "I told him" preferred?

Comment: @Alenanno: It depends on the context. You could use either.

Comment: Considering this appears to be a poem, a bit of ambiguity around 'crying' doesn't seem inappropriate.